# Flask API breaks at long Cypher query

Tags: python, flask, neo4j, docker, py2neo

I'm building an API in Flask that talks to a neo4j db. One particularly large query (15 minutes+) breaks the API. Breaking means the Docker container in which it runs stops without logging the request. The trouble is I can't reproduce the error when I run the API locally.

What I think I need is a way to run the query using py2neo, then return an arbitrary response *without* waiting for the query to finish.

```
def post(self):
    g.cypher.run("MATCH a-[r]-b SET r.cost = "
    "CASE WHEN r.cost <1 THEN 0.01*exp(4.60517*(r.costx+0.01)) ELSE r.cost END " 
    "SET r.costx = "
    "CASE WHEN r.costx < 1 THEN r.costx + 0.01 ELSE r.costx END "
    "RETURN r")
    return make_response(jsonify({'success': 'all relationship costs increased'}), 200)
```

I'm really not an ops guy so any broader insights to this conundrum are most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much data do you have in that database? You might be better off running start r=rel(*) ...

why do you return r in the first place?

I would batch your query and add this condition:

```
START r=rel(*)
WITH r
WHERE r.cost < 1 OR r.costx < 1
WITH r
SKIP {batchSize} LIMIT 100000
SET r.cost = CASE WHEN r.cost < 1 THEN 0.01*exp(4.60517*(r.costx+0.01)) ELSE r.cost END 
WITH r WHERE r.costx < 1
SET r.costx = r.costx + 0.01
```

or better run it in two passes:

```
START r=rel(*)
WITH r
WHERE r.cost < 1
WITH r
SKIP {batchSize} LIMIT 100000
SET r.cost = 0.01*exp(4.60517*(r.costx+0.01))
```

and same for cost.x

Comment: Simply not returning r solves the issue. Another potential solution lies with the fact that the default heap memory is not suitable for large queries. Thanks!

Comment: I tried your suggested queries without batching and they perform much better than mine. Why is "START r=rel(*)" so much faster than "MATCH a-[r]-b"?